# Can I highlight the line at which a command was issued in zshell?

Tags: unix, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using [zsh](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsh) and oh-my-zsh and would like to easily find the start of a i.e. ack or find by changing the color of the line the command started. Is it possible to change the line color as soon as the command was issued but not for outputs to stdout/stderr?

Also can I color stderr differently than stdout?

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/q/610058/195224

Comment: Regarding your STDERR coloring, there was a really lengthy discussion on the zsh mailing list (http://www.zsh.org/mla/users//2004/msg00617.html), and a few years later another try (http://www.zsh.org/mla/users//2009/msg00498.html). The solution proposed in the later post seems to work, but has some issues.